# Starting an application remotely

Tags: python, windows, cmd, windows-7

I know locally you can start an application with **START** but how can I start a program remotely with CMD or Python?

Comment: By remotely do you mean via a different computer, a different Python program? Please expand

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Remote Desktop Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_software) there are plenty of those that are cheap or free.

You can also use SSH to take control of a linux shell.

You can also use [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) or ncat to have your computer listen for connections on a given port and to turn over a command prompt (windows) or shell terminal (Linux) to anyone who connects to that port.